# Django - Ajax modal login/registration

Tags: ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, django-registration

I have a project in which I need to pop a modal window for not authenticated users.

This modal will allow to login directly **or** create an account.

So it will contain two forms:

- `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`
- `registration.forms.RegistrationForm`

[image: Modal tabbed forms]

Here is my view to get both forms:

```
def ajax_registration(request):
    obj = {
        'login_form': AuthenticationForm(),
        'registration_form': RegistrationForm(),
    }
    return render(request, 'common/ajax_registration.html', obj)
```

And my template displaying the forms tabbed

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">{% trans 'Login' %}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">{% trans 'Registration' %}</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    {{ login_form|bootstrap }}
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
    {{ registration_form|bootstrap }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Question is: Since I'm using ajax to display this modal, How can I validate the selected form, preferably using the already written [`django-registrations register`](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/views.html#registration.views.register) & [`django.contrib.auth login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) views ?

Comment: have you sucessfully implement it? Could you share this piece of code somwhere on github? It will nice point culminant :-)

Comment: Good idea. I just have some issues with the ajax registration. I'm going to push my files on github (I don't know how to package them though)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Glideh/django-ajax-login) you go. Any improve is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to Maddog's answer you need some javascript to submit the form back to the URL that rendered the form. Using jquery it could be something like:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(e.target);

        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url YOUR_REGISTRATION_URL %}',
            type: 'post',
            data: account_form.serialize() + '&' + form.serialize(),
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert(thrownError); },
            success: function(){}
        })
 })
```

You don't need to do it with a form submit element, you could use any element with $().click(), of course.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I know how to manage the Javascript part. I mentioned ajax just to specify the context which will eventually involve some json or html responses.

Comment: I'm searching more specifically how to process both forms by using [`django-registrations register`](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/views.html#registration.views.register) & [`django.contrib.auth login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) views

Comment: ok, I see. So you need their registration.views.register if it's a new user and django.contrib.auth.views.login if it's a already created registration? Shouldn't you use those two views directly instead of using the forms?

Comment: I would like to. But how can I use both in the same template ?

Comment: You could load them both with an AJAX call ($.load() in jquery). If you make two urls that go the respective views, you can load one in the login tab and one in the register tab. You probably need to override the formname, because they probably both use form as a name.

Comment: That seems to be a good idea. Question will be how to prevent redirections and get json reponses instead for successful login/registration

Comment: OK. you could make two views, one for success and one for failure. They emit the json you want. Then you could use those for redirecting. They will end up in $.ajax.success or $.ajax.error, so you could handle them in your template.

Comment: For the record, I have [wrapped the registration view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508217)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
def ajax_registration(request):
    login_form, registration_form = False, False
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "email" in request.POST: # some condition to distinguish between login and registration form
            login_form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
            if login_form.is_valid():
                # log in
        else:
            registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if registration_form.is_valid():
                # register

    obj = {
        'login_form': login_form if login_form else AuthenticationForm(),
        'registration_form': registration_form if registration_form else RegistrationForm(),
    }
    return render(request, 'common/ajax_registration.html', obj)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 2 issues here: 1 - if the user fills the email then finally wants to login directly, it'll break (so it have to take the selected tab, I will do a JS updating a hidden input for that). 2 - Is there any way to route to the existing registration views in order to take advantage of the already implemented mechanics ?

Comment: 1. - sure by the '"email" in ..' I just meant some condition to distinguish between those 2 forms 2. - what view do you have in mind? I thought you just want to carry out the registration / login on the background using some auth API... well I don't know this app too well, so I can't halp you with this much

Comment: I am trying to do something similar by submiting django-registration forms via ajax, but I am getting a 403 . Has anybody succeded processing the forms ?