# Django - Ajax registration

Tags: django, django-views, django-registration

I am trying to allow registration (using this [`django-registration register`](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/views.html#registration.views.register) view) to one of my applications from a modal dialog.

Since this form is in a modal box, I'd like to get an json reponse on success (instead of the default redirection)

How can I use this view ([`django-registration register`](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/views.html#registration.views.register)) to manage the registration and send back a json response on success ?

---

I know how to make ajax/json responses, the question is how to use the django-registration view without the redirection behavior or wrap it into an other view to manage the response.

Comment: How do you render form with its eventual errors at the first place?

Comment: I reload the form using the standard http response. So if I receive http response I simply load it into the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change the urls.py to wrap the existing view with another functionality. To do that you have to create a new backend package in backends folder and change urls.py there while keeping everything else intact, or you could just go ahead and modify the existing urls.py in the backend package.

I have not tested this, but it should work.

Point url to the new view:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^register/$', register_wrap,
    {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'},
    name='registration_register'),

# your new view that wraps the existing one
def register_wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):

    # call the standard view here
    response = register(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # check if response is a redirect
    if response.status_code == 302:
        # this was redirection, send json response instead
    else:
        # just return as it is
        return response
```

If you are going to need this for more views you can just create a decorator using this.

Comment: This seems much more suited for my needs. Let me try it

Comment: No problem. Thanks for asking as well I learned a new thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Why I would do is to check if `request.is_ajax()` in your normal after-successfull-registration-redirect view and return json response there.

Answer (score 0):

You ask how you can use the existing view to manage the registration and send back a json response on success. Since the HttpResponseRedirect is pretty much hard coded in the view, you can't use the view as it is. Instead, either fork it, or write your own view and change the urls.py so that r'^register/$' directs to your new view.

As far as the json response is concerned, on success you can do something like this:

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json

def register_ajax(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict(success=True, **dict_containing_data)))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I now understand what you're asking for, but have no experience with wrapping views like that, so unfortunately can not help you with that.